# Calculate volume difference between twice fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

```
    import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const DataFetch = () => {
  const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function FetchData() {
      await axios.get("https://api.hotbit.io/api/v1/allticker").then((data) => {
        setCoinData(
          data.data.ticker.sort((a, b) => a.symbol.localeCompare(b.symbol))
        );
      });
    }
    FetchData();
  }, []);

  function fetchCoin() {
    const coinArr = coinData.map((coin, i) => coin.base_volume);
    console.log(coinArr[0]);
    return coinArr;
  }

  return (
    <table className="table-auto border-separate border border-slate-500">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th className="border border-slate-600">Cặp</th>
          <th className="border border-slate-600">Giá</th>
          <th className="border border-slate-600">BaseVol</th>
          <th className="border border-slate-600">QuoteVol</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {coinData.map((coin, idx) => (
          <tr key={idx} c>
            <td className="border border-slate-600">{coin.symbol}</td>
            <td className="border border-slate-600">{coin.buy}</td>
            <td className="border border-slate-600">{coin.base_volume}</td>
            <td className="border border-slate-600">{coin.quote_volume}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

export default DataFetch;
I have a question. ( sorry for my grammar cuz I am a Vietnamese)

I have created a react project for creating a table of coin pair, coin price, coin volume. I have fetched data from that API above. My table rerenders once my data is updated.So, I wanna calculate the difference of volume of each coin pair between Twice consecutive fetching , and then convert it into percentage. Thanks for any help

Comment: It seems like you want to do some calculations based on the old state. Once you receive the data the second time from your back-end, don't overwrite the current state straight away. You can use your old state here, to do the calculations required and then overwrite the old state with setCoinData

Comment: can you explain more? May I have your facebook or email?

Comment: Do you have a function that calculates the difference? Start off by creating that. Given two arrays of coin data, calculate the difference on them. Then you can use that function in your .then() statement and pass old state and newly fetched data to it